# how to scroll one mobile page at a time on a long text in Android ScrollView?

Tags: android, kotlin, text, scrollview

I try to scroll one whole screen size page in every mobile device on a long text within a TextView in a ScrollView but all I got is scrolling to the bottom of the whole Text which is like this:

```
binding.scrollView.post{
            binding.scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
        }
```

I want it scrolls page by page not the whole text. here is the XML code of the ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
    android:background="@color/whitef5_background"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/holder_player_bar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:riv_corner_radius="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
            style="@style/TextBold16Black2128"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorLink="@color/app_orange"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:text="Reading Title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title_fa"
            style="@style/TextMed14Gray8f"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:text="مطلب ساختگی"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/div"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:background="@color/grayDBEC"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_title_fa"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            style="@style/TextMed14Black2128"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:text="@string/reading_test_speech"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/div"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_test"
            style="@style/ButtonMed14White"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_orange_button"
            android:text="@string/reading_go_to_questions_btn_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

if there's a method or if I need to change or note something please update me with it so I can have the right function. thank you.

Comment: Use viewpager2 with recyclerview adapter